# ArcGIS javascript api Rendering some parts of the Featurelayer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm confused how to render only some parts of a feature layer. Since all the given classbreak rendering samples are rendering the whole feature layer, is there any method to render only a few of the polygons in the feature layer (already have the Object IDs).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you want to use Definition Expression since you know the OID's.

[API doc for setdefinitionexpression](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer.html#setdefinitionexpression), and an [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/fl_hover.html)